# How can I get different type in function template

Tags: c++, templates

I define below function template, But I meet some problem. Please kindly help me out. Thanks!

```
template <typename T>
void Insert(CMyObj obj_, std::vector<T>& vec_)
{
    if(T is bool type)
        vec_.push_back(obj_.AsBool());
    if(T is string type)
        vec_.push_back(obj_.AsString());
}
```

I can call function template as below, How should I implement my Insert().

```
CMyObj  obj;
std::vector<bool> vec1;
Insert<bool>(obj, vec1);

std::vector<string> vec2;
Insert<string>(obj, vec2);
```

Comment: Will `void Insert(T obj_, std::vector<T>& vec_)` do?

Comment: I think the vector has to be of type T as well. That is, the vector also has to be of type string in this example.

Comment: @herohuyongtao No, As you can see, obj_ is not a T, and it has `AsBool()`/`AsString()` two functions which will call base on T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if the template parameter can be deduced from the arguments (which it can in this case) you can simply call it via "Insert(obj, vec1)": if vec1 is `std::vector<bool>`, T will be bool etc...

Secondly, I would define a second function template, specifically to extract a typed value from your variant-like CMyObj:

```
template <typename T>
T GetValue(const CMyObj& obj); // Note: no definition

// These should be inline or in a .cpp file to prevent linker issues
template <>
inline bool GetValue(const CMyObj& obj) { return CMyObj.AsBool(); }

template <>
inline std::string GetValue(const CMyObj& obj) { return CMyObj.AsString(); }
```

You can then implement Insert as:

```
template <typename T>
void Insert(CMyObj obj_, std::vector<T>& vec_)
{
  vec_.push_back(GetValue<T>(obj_));
}
```

If you try to insert it into a vector with a value type for which GetValue has not been specialized, it won't compile. Which is what you'd want I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is the error you are facing, but you can change your code as below:-

```
template <typename T>
void Insert(T obj_, std::vector<T>& vec_)
{
        vec_.push_back(obj_);
}




CMyObj  obj;
std::vector<bool> vec1;
Insert<bool>(obj.AsBool(), vec1);

std::vector<string> vec2;
Insert<string>(obj.AsString(), vec2);
```